# How to run Quicksql?

Tags: macos, quick-sql

As I am running the Quicksql, an error arises which is as shown blew.
The link:
https://github.com/Qihoo360/Quicksql/blob/master/doc/BUILD_doc.md

ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/usr/local/qsql-0.6/lib/netty-common-4.1.16.Final.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Elasticsearch Embedded Server is starting up, waiting....
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/qsql-0.6/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/wangjinsa/Downloads/Compressed/spark-2.4/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Elasticsearch Embedded Server has started!! Your query is running...
Input: SELECT * FROM depts INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM student WHERE city in ('FRAMINGHAM', 'BROCKTON', 'CONCORD')) FILTERED ON depts.name = FILTERED.type 
.........

Comment: Hi, please could you [edit] your question to include the command and error message from the screenshot as text? That will make it easier to read, and easier for other people with the same error to find in future.